# Подмена данных от сервера

Tags: json, api, сеть

Есть приложение которое отправляет на сервер запрос и принимает от него ответ, в зависимости от ответа принимает решение - разрешить ли пользователю доступ к приложению или нет. Как мне заменить этот ответ, к примеру `{"code":"1","reason":"not registered"}` на `{"code":"0"}`?

Пробовал искать ответ в поисковике, смотрел какие-то программы, но ничего нормального не нашёл.

Если такое можно реализовать - прошу вас. Желательно чтобы работало на Linux.

Comment: Что за приложение? Web?

Comment: @SwaD, кастомизированный клиент open-source игры "DDNet"

Comment: Сам response веб сервера, не имея к нему доступ, вы изменить не сможете. Только если получив данные в виде json (что для go, к примеру, просто слайс байтов) средствами вашего языка программирования отредактировать под ваши требования